# How Do I Add/Remove a UIBarButtonItem to/from a UIToolbar After Items Have Already Been Added?

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, xamarin, toolbar

I am working in Xamarin.iOS and I have UIToolbar that needs to be able to add and remove buttons from it programmatically at run-time.

I have tried several different approaches using:  _buttons is a UIBarButtonItem[]

```
SetItems(_buttons, false)
```

and the toolbar never seems to update.

I initialize the toolbar when the app starts up with its main three buttons.  When certain things happen, I need to be able to remove buttons from the toolbar as well as add new items to the toolbar.

I have also tried calling:

```
SetNeedsDisplay()
```

after calling:

```
SetItems(_buttons, false)
```

and this doesn't update the toolbar items either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the reason it is not changing because LayoutSubviews is called all the time and overrides your SetItems. Use constructor to populate toolbar first time

```
public partial class CustomUiToolbar : UIToolbar
{
    public CustomUiToolbar (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        var _UIBarButtonItemArrayOne = new UIBarButtonItem[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var _item = new UIBarButtonItem(i.ToString(), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, null);
            _item.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
            _UIBarButtonItemArrayOne[i] = _item;
        }
        //var __UIBarButtonItemArrayTwo = new UIBarButtonItem[2];
        //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        //{
        //    var _item = new UIBarButtonItem(i.ToString(), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, null);
        //    _item.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
        //    __UIBarButtonItemArrayTwo[i] = _item;
        //}
        SetItems(_UIBarButtonItemArrayOne, true);
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();



    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuri S, this was the answer I was looking for!  Moving the setup code out of LayoutSubviews() and putting it in the constructor did the trick!